# Magento 2.3.3 - Changing default header size for an image

Tags: header, magento2.3.3

First of all, I'm fairly new to Magento. And my question is how do I change the default header size for an image? The site I'm working on is upgrading from `Magento version 2.3.2 to 2.3.3.` And in `version 2.3.2,` the size of the image we used was not specified for the header. There the image was fine and at its normal size. So, when I tried using the same image in `Magento version 2.3.3,` the image is "squished"/compacted because the default header size seems to be half the size in the new Magento version.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By header size image I am assuming you want to customise the logo, so for that you need to extend 
`magentoroot_dir/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` so for doing its recommended to create a new theme and then copy your **default.xml** file at below path:

`magentoroot_dir/app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">50</argument> 
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I tried you suggestion, unfortunately it did not work for me. But, I did discover I could manually change the size of the logo via the Magento Admin panel. Thanks again for the help though.